# Clear select2 without triggering change event

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 input that I'm using and on 'change' I'm grabbing the values and performing an action. I'm trying to clear that select2 without triggering a change event. Is this possible?

To clear the select2 I'm using the following code:

```
$docInput.select2('data', null);
```

This clears the input as desired, but also triggers a change event which runs through my other code. There must be a way to silence the trigger. Any ideas?

Comment: You could do a test in your onchange event and make sure that the input isn't empty before you do whatever it is you're doing in that function.

Comment: Can you provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have?

Comment: @Jnatalzia I'm currently using your idea as a 'fix' but I'm curious if clearing a select2 without triggering a change event is actually possible. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: AFAIK `.select2('data', null)` does **not** trigger any event.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/xDUUg/247/) for Ryan where change occurs.

Comment: @Dom That looks weird.. According to the docs and the [source](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/6eb74930d58f7265839ecf256eedc72ef29d068b/select2.js#L2288), the `change` event would only be fired if the optional 3rd parameter is true as in `.select2('data', null, true)`

Comment: It definitely fires a change on clear...

Comment: @MikeFielden You're right, you need to explicitly pass `false` https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/6eb74930d58f7265839ecf256eedc72ef29d068b/select2.js#L2036 it is worth reporting a bug.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe all you need is:

`$docInput.select2('data', null, false);`

Comment: Yes this should do as a temporary fix, I'll open an issue/PR later today.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 67):

You can use the following with Select2 4.x

```
$docInput.val(null).trigger('change.select2');
```

Comment: Is this the only way you could find?

Comment: This works because it specifically triggering the `change` event with the namespace that Select2 is looking for (`.select2`), so other event handlers will not be triggered. This namespace _might_ change in the future, but it's pretty unlikely.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked without triggering the 'change' event on the original <select> elements. Thanks!

Comment: This saved me some time! Thanks :)

Comment: Works like a charm! The only solution that works and is straight forward. Solves the problem if you have an on-change event applied to multiple select2 dropdowns that update via ajax. Hooray!

Comment: $('.select_auto').on('select2:selecting', function(e) {

When trigger change, above function should be trigger, but its not. I changed selecting to change but still not working

Comment: My issue was that `trigger('change')` was firing the `click` event on a parent element. `trigger('change.select2')` works perfectly!