# How to manually select an item using AJAX, Select2 and the "val" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Trying to figure out how to change the selected item of a select2 box after the page loads for the first time (and after it has loaded data from a ajax api call)

I tried using the below, but I cant get them to call after the ajax data has loaded?

```
$series2.val('2');
$series2.trigger('change');
```

The documentation says that it cannot be done using the val function (see here https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items) and I do not want to do this with a custom API call that provides a "selected" value - as this does not work with templating.

This is NOT a duplicate of [Select2 auto trigger event change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690487/select2-auto-trigger-event-change)

```
    var $make2 = $(".make2");
    var $series2 = $(".series2");
    $make2.select2().on('change', function() {
        $series2.empty();
        if ($make2.val() !== null) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/') }}" + "/api/series/" + $make2.val(),
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    $series2.select2({
                        data: data,
                        templateSelection: function(result) {
                            return result['text'];
                        },
                        templateResult: function(result) {
                            if (!result['id']) {
                                return result['text'];
                            };
                            var final =
                                '<div>' +
                                    '<strong>' + result['text'] + '</strong>' +
                                    '<ul class="list-unstyled">' +
                                        '<li><em>' + result['make'] + '</em></li>' +
                                        '<li><em>' + result['category'] + '</em></li>' +
                                    '</ul>' +
                                '</div>';
                            return final;
                        },
                        escapeMarkup: function(result) {
                            return result;
                        },
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```