# How to prevent get value selected option got duplicated in select2 function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have `select` function using jQuery select2. I have problem with displaying value that has been selected from the previous form.

In my page details, I want to display the selected value that user has choose. The also can update if they want.

[image]

How do I show it up as selected  based on the id that I have retrieve form the api `${e.tag.id}` instead of like this ?

[image]

```
-Red
-Yellow
-New  -> selected 
-Others
```

Should have only show `New` once.

I will get all the value first from my api url then I will append it on the `id=tag`. If user have not put the tag yet it will display the `select tag` for them but if the user already inserted the tag previously, value will be displayed on the `<select>` box area. But I don't want it to show up on the `<option>` because it will get duplicated.

This is what I have tried

```
  $('#tag').select2({
                placeholder: "Select Tag",
                allowClear: true
   });

 const getTagList = () =>{
        axios.get(`url`)
            .then(function (res) { 
                if(res.data.status == 'success')
                    {
                        if(res.data.result.length > 0)
                        {
                            res.data.result.map((e) => {
                                $('#tag').append(`<option value="${e.tag.id}">${e.tag.title}</option>`);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
        
        }
```

```
if(e.tag.id == '0'){ tagInfo+= ` <option value="" hidden>Select Tag</option>`;}
 else { tagInfo+= `<option value="${e.tag.id}" selected >${e.tag.title}</option>`;}


                    

  <!-- list tag -->

    <div class="row mb-4 align-items-end">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Tag</label>
         <div class="form-control-wrap">
           <select class="" name="tag" id="tag">
               ${tagInfo}
           </select> 
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>         
    </div>
```

I already read the value from the database and show it up on the text. But I don't want it to sit on the  if the value is same as in the  it should only appears once. Instead it should just shows as selected. But with my current code it appears twice in the  list.

[image: it give me no result found if no option were chosen yet]

[image: and only this if option already chosen]

Comment: You want to remove based on value or text ?

Comment: I already read the value from the database and show it up on the text. But I don't want it to sit on the `<option>` if the value is same as in the `<option>` it should only appears once. But with my current code it appears twice in the `<option>` list.

Comment: if value are duplicate in database , you can select distinct record.

Comment: and also you can check in jQuery before adding into select.

Comment: You will need to check for the duplicates before you append it to the select2 and then 
make sure after you append them you will have to invoke a method called `trigger("change")` refer to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690487/select2-auto-trigger-event-change)

Comment: @HirenPatel no no, It did not duplicate in my database. I just dont want it to sit on my `<option>`  I want it to show as `selected`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can do it in this way.

=> For Binding Your Select

```
 const getTagList = () =>{
        axios.get(`url`)
            .then(function (res) { 
                if(res.data.status == 'success')
                    {
                        if(res.data.result.length > 0)
                        {
                            
                            res.data.result.map((e) => {
                                if($("#tag option[value='"${e.tag.id}"']").length==0){
                                      $('#tag').append(`<option value="${e.tag.id}">${e.tag.title}</option>`);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
        
        }
```

Comment: I will not be able to retrieve the value if the user have previously inserted. I want to display the inserted value in the `select text` but not in the `select <option>` that is why i put the `${tagInfo}`

Comment: what ${tagInfo} is contain, can you please share /

Comment: means you have option in  ${tagInfo} and you are also binding option from api. Am I right ?

Comment: yes. If user already choose the option. It will display in the ` text in the select box area` but I don't want it to appear in the <option> it should only shows the text as `selected` in the option list instead of add another option.

Comment: in the `${tagInfo} else ` I want it to show just the name of the `${e.tag.title}` but when user click on dropdown list it will show that which the `${e.tag.title}` as selected.

Comment: I've updated answer , can you please check. I've check element is exist or not before adding it.

Comment: I have inserted the picture of the current update code. It give me `no result` if the option is not chosen yet. and if its alredy chosen the other option is missing

Comment: can you please share your code on codepen ?

Comment: I've changed condition, Can you please check it, and also share code on codepen if posible.