# Change the multi select option text, when the option text is changed jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a form where the user is allowed to add the options manually to the multiple select box. I've provided a preview field(for showing the preview) and a default value field(to select the default values if the user needs). There is a field for the user to enter the options. Once the user clicks the `Add` button after entering an option, it will be displayed in div provided. Each option can also be edited.

When the option is Added, that option will be added to the default value field as dropdown and to the preview field as dropdown. This is done simultaneouly, whenever an option is added.

When the option is edited, (according to my logic) the option in the div should be edited and the option in the default value and preview option should be edited as well. This is how I tried:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="MultiSelect_Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="min-width: 75% !important;">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="FieldType">Multi Select</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group required">
                                <label for="MultiSelect_Label" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Label Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MultiSelect_Label" name="MultiSelect_Label" value=''>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="MultiSelect_DefaultValues" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Default Value</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <select id="MultiSelect_DefaultValues" name="MultiSelect_DefaultValues[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="width: 160px;">
                                        <option value="0">---Select---</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="manualEntryDiv">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group required">
                                <label for="MultiSelect_Options" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Options</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MultiSelect_Options" name="MultiSelect_Options" value=''>
                                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="MultiSelect_optionAdd" name="MultiSelect_optionAdd">
                                      </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="result" id="MultiSelect_mydiv"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: -20px;">
                                <label for="MultiSelect_Description" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Description</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="MultiSelect_Description" name="MultiSelect_Description" row='3'></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group required">
                                <label for="MultiSelect_Status" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Status</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="MultiSelect_Status" id="MultiSelect_Status">
                                        <option value="1">Active</option>
                                        <option value="0">In-Active</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="MultiSelect_Preview" id="MultiSelect_PreviewID" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Preview</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <select id="MultiSelect_Preview" name="MultiSelect_Preview[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="width: 160px;">
                                        <option value="0">---Select---</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearcontrols();" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" id="MultiSelect_Save" name="MultiSelect_Save" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

$("#MultiSelect_optionAdd").click(function(){
            if($("#MultiSelect_Options").val() == ""){
                MyNotif.Show("Please enter an option","warning");
            } else {
                if($("#MultiSelect_optionAdd").val() == "Add"){
                    var optionvalue = $("#MultiSelect_Options").val();
                    $("#MultiSelect_mydiv").append("<span id='span" + a + "' class='editbutton'>" + optionvalue + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href='javascript:void(0)' ><i class='fa fa-close btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-remove btn-icon remove' id='remove" + a + "' style='display: none;'></i></a><a href='javascript:void(0)'><i class='fa fa-pencil btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-edit btn-icon edit' id='edit" + a + "' style='display: none; margin-right:10px;'></i></a></span><br/>");
                    $("#MultiSelect_Preview").append('<option value="value-'+ optionvalue +'" id="options'+ a +'">' + optionvalue + '</option>');
                    $("#MultiSelect_DefaultValues").append('<option value="value-'+ optionvalue +'" id="defaultOptions'+ a +'">' + optionvalue + '</option>');
                    a = a + 1;
                    $("#MultiSelect_Options").val("");
                } else if ($("#MultiSelect_optionAdd").val() == "Update") {
                    $("#"+spanid).text($("#MultiSelect_Options").val()).append("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href='javascript:void(0)' ><i class='fa fa-close btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-remove btn-icon remove' id='" + removebuttonid + "' style='display: none;'></i></a><a href='javascript:void(0)'><i class='fa fa-pencil btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-edit btn-icon edit' id='" + editbuttonid + "' style='display: none; margin-right:10px;'></i></a>");
                    $("#MultiSelect_optionAdd").val("Add");
                    $("#"+optionsid).text($("#MultiSelect_Options").val());
                    $("#"+defaultOptionsid).text($("#MultiSelect_Options").val());
                    $("#"+defaultOptionsid).val("value-"+$("#MultiSelect_Options").val());
                    $("#MultiSelect_Options").val("");
                }

                $('.remove').click(function(){
                    removebuttonid = $(this).attr("id");
                    spanid = removebuttonid.replace('remove', 'span');
                    optionsid = removebuttonid.replace('remove', 'options');
                    defaultOptionsid = removebuttonid.replace('remove', 'defaultOptions');

                    $("#"+spanid).next("br").remove();
                    $("#"+spanid).remove(); 
                    $("#"+optionsid).remove();
                    $("#"+defaultOptionsid).remove();
                }); 

                $(".edit").click(function(){
                    addButtonValue = "Update"
                    $("#MultiSelect_optionAdd").val(addButtonValue);
                    editbuttonid = $(this).attr("id");
                    spanid = editbuttonid.replace('edit', 'span');
                    optionsid = editbuttonid.replace('edit', 'options');
                    defaultOptionsid = editbuttonid.replace('edit', 'defaultOptions');

                    removebuttonid = editbuttonid.replace('edit', 'remove');

                    var value = ($("#"+spanid).text()).trim();
                    $("#MultiSelect_Options").val(value);
                });             
            }
        });
```

Here, whenever I add an option, that option gets added to the div, default value and preview fields. Whatever I add as an option, it gets added.

But, the problem is, when I edit the option I provide, the option inside the div gets changed. But, the option in the default value and preview displays the same text which was provided previously. But, when I inspect the element, I can see the edited text as well as edited value. But, the previously provided option is only shown. The edited text is not shown.

I don't know what's wrong with the above code. What should I change in this?

Comment: I think you should refresh the select element after you update the elements inside,  to reproduce the select structure. ike: `$('#MultiSelect_DefaultValues').multiselect("refresh");`

Comment: @Qsprec: Where should I place this line?

Comment: @Qsprec If I add this line, it shows `multiselect` is not a function.

Comment: Are you using jquery multiselect? If yes then I will answer but if you are not , there is an another problem here.

Comment: @Qsprec I'm using select-2.

Comment: So try this one. This one should work. `var selectElem = $('#MultiSelect_DefaultValues').select2(); selectElem.trigger('change');`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819709/clear-select2-without-triggering-change-event#31856728