# jqGrid with select2. In edition mode, when navigation rows, values from row is not substituted in select

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-select2

```js
var dataTable = [{
                id: '10',
                date_create: '27-06-2019',
                department_name: 'Отдел информационных систем',
                status_name: 'В очереди на выполнение',
                type_work_name: 'Не работает Интернет',
                phone: '99-99-99',
                auditory_name: 'В-200',
                inventory_number: '24274',
                comment: 'something goes wrong',
                extra_fields: [{
                        "tw_value_field_id": "4",
                        "tw_field_value": "Microsoft Excel",
                        "type_work_name_field_id": "1",
                        "field_name": "Название программного обеспечения",
                        "field_datatype": "select",
                        "type_work_name_field_value": "Microsoft Word:Microsoft Word;Microsoft Excel:Microsoft Excel;Microsoft PowerPoint:Microsoft PowerPoint"
                    },
                    {
                        "tw_value_field_id": "5",
                        "tw_field_value": "Problem №1",
                        "type_work_name_field_id": "3",
                        "field_name": "Примечание",
                        "field_datatype": "textarea",
                        "type_work_name_field_value": null
                    },
                    {
                        "tw_value_field_id": "6",
                        "tw_field_value": "99-99-55",
                        "type_work_name_field_id": "2",
                        "field_name": "Телефон",
                        "field_datatype": "input",
                        "type_work_name_field_value": null
                    }
                ]
            },



            {
                id: '20',
                date_create: '28-06-2019',
                department_name: 'Отдел информационных систем',
                status_name: 'В очереди на выполнение',
                type_work_name: 'Не работает Интернет',
                phone: '99-99-98',
                auditory_name: 'В-201',
                inventory_number: '24275',
                comment: 'something goes wrong',
                extra_fields: [{
                        "tw_value_field_id": "7",
                        "tw_field_value": "Microsoft PowerPoint",
                        "type_work_name_field_id": "1",
                        "field_name": "Название программного обеспечения",
                        "field_datatype": "select",
                        "type_work_name_field_value": "Microsoft Word:Microsoft Word;Microsoft Excel:Microsoft Excel;Microsoft PowerPoint:Microsoft PowerPoint"
                    },
                    {
                        "tw_value_field_id": "8",
                        "tw_field_value": "Problem №2",
                        "type_work_name_field_id": "3",
                        "field_name": "Примечание",
                        "field_datatype": "textarea",
                        "type_work_name_field_value": null
                    },
                    {
                        "tw_value_field_id": "9",
                        "tw_field_value": "88-99-55",
                        "type_work_name_field_id": "2",
                        "field_name": "Телефон",
                        "field_datatype": "input",
                        "type_work_name_field_value": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: '30',
                date_create: '20-06-2019',
                department_name: 'Подготовительное отделение',
                status_name: 'В очереди на выполнение',
                type_work_name: 'Переустановка ОС',
                phone: '99-99-00',
                auditory_name: 'В-202',
                inventory_number: '24276',
                comment: 'something goes wrong',
                extra_fields: [{
                        "tw_value_field_id": "10",
                        "tw_field_value": "Microsoft Word",
                        "type_work_name_field_id": "1",
                        "field_name": "Название программного обеспечения",
                        "field_datatype": "select",
                        "type_work_name_field_value": "Microsoft Word:Microsoft Word;Microsoft Excel:Microsoft Excel;Microsoft PowerPoint:Microsoft PowerPoint"
                    },
                    {
                        "tw_value_field_id": "11",
                        "tw_field_value": "Problem №3",
                        "type_work_name_field_id": "3",
                        "field_name": "Примечание",
                        "field_datatype": "textarea",
                        "type_work_name_field_value": null
                    },
                    {
                        "tw_value_field_id": "12",
                        "tw_field_value": "77-99-55",
                        "type_work_name_field_id": "2",
                        "field_name": "Телефон",
                        "field_datatype": "input",
                        "type_work_name_field_value": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#table-application").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local", 
                data: dataTable,
                colNames: ["Номер заявки в системе", "Дата создания", "Отдел", "Статус",
                    "Тип работ", "Номер телефона для связи", "Аудитория", "Инвентарный номер",
                    "Описание проблемы", ""
                ],
                colModel: [{
                        name: "id",
                        id: "id"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "date_create",
                        id: "date_create"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "department_name",
                        id: "department_name",
                    },
                    {
                        name: "status_name",
                        id: "status_name",
                        editable: true,
                        edittype: "select",
                        editoptions: {
                            value: "1:В очереди на выполнение;2:Принята в работу;3:Закрыта"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "type_work_name",
                        id: "type_work_name",
                        editable: true,
                        edittype: "select",
                        editoptions: {
                            value: "1:Установка телефона; 2:Переустановка ОС; 3:Ремонт ПК и техники; 4:Заправка/замена картриджа; 5:Не работает Интернет"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "phone",
                        id: "phone",
                        editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: "auditory_name",
                        id: "auditory_name",
                        editable: true,
                        edittype: "select",
                        editoptions: {
                            value: "1:В-200; 2:В-201; 3:В-202; 4:K-300"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "inventory_number",
                        id: "inventory_number",
                        editable: true,
                        edittype: "select",
                        editoptions: {
                            value: "1:876547; 2:453213; 3:342123; 4:567496; 5:409325; 6:24274; 7:24275; 8:24276",
                            dataInit: function (el) {
                                $(el).select2({
                                    language: 'ru',
                                    width: '100%'
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "comment",
                        id: "comment",
                        editable: true,
                        edittype: "textarea"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "extra_fields",
                        id: "extra_fields",
                        classes: "extra-field",
                        hidden: true,
                        title: false,
                        editable: false,
                        jsonmap: "extra_fields",
                        formatter: function (cellvalue) {
                            if (cellvalue != null) {
                                return JSON.stringify(cellvalue);
                            } else
                                return cellvalue;
                        }
                    }
                ],
                pager: "#pager",
                height: "auto",
                autowidth: true,
                forceFit: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                autoencode: true,
                caption: "Список заявок",
                rownumbers: true,
                subGrid: true,
                subGridBeforeExpand: function (pID, id) {
                    //получаем значение поля extra_fields по id выбранной строки

                    extra_field_val = $('#table-application').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'extra_fields');
                    var jsonArray = $.parseJSON(extra_field_val);

                    //если дополнительная информация по заявке есть, раскрываем список
                    if (jsonArray.length > 0) {
                        console.log(true);
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                },
                subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
                    var subgrid_table_id;
                    subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";

                    jQuery("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id +
                        "' class='scroll'></table>");


                    extra_field_val = $('#table-application').jqGrid('getCell', row_id,
                        'extra_fields');
                    var response = $.parseJSON(extra_field_val);
                    //задаем массив для подтаблицы

                    var element_name, element_mode, col_name, objData;
                    var subColNames, subColModel, subData, selectValue;

                    subColNames = [];
                    subColModel = [];
                    subData = [];
                    objData = {};

                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

                        element_name = {};
                        element_name = response[i]['field_name'];
                        subColNames.push(element_name);

                        element_mode = {};
                        element_mode = {
                            name: "col_" + response[i]['tw_value_field_id'],
                            id: "col_" + response[i]['tw_value_field_id'],
                            editable: true
                        };
                        subColModel.push(element_mode);

                        if (response[i]['field_datatype'] == 'select') {
                            element_mode['edittype'] = "select";
                            selectValue = response[i]['type_work_name_field_value'];

                            element_mode['editoptions'] = {
                                value: selectValue
                            };
                        }

                        col_name = "col_" + response[i]['tw_value_field_id'];
                        objData[col_name] = response[i]['tw_field_value'];
                    }


                    subColNames.push("");

                    subColModel.push({
                        name: "id",
                        id: "id",
                        hidden: true,
                        editable: true,
                        editrules: {
                            edithidden: false
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(subColModel);
                    objData['id'] = response[0]['id'];
                    subData.push(objData);


                    var lastSel;

                    jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                        datatype: "local",
                        data: subData,
                        colNames: subColNames,
                        colModel: subColModel,
                        height: '75%',
                        caption: "Дополнительная информация",
                        onSelectRow: function (id) {
                            if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                                jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).restoreRow(lastSel);
                                lastSel = id;
                            }
                            jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).editRow(id, true);
                        },
                        editurl: 'clientArray'
                    });


                },
                editurl: 'clientArray'

            });

            $("#table-application").navGrid("#pager", {
                edit: true,
                add: false,
                del: false,
                search: false,
                refresh: false,
                editicon: "none",
                edittext: "Редактировать",
            }, {
                /*hier setting of edit form*/

            });

        });
```

```css
 .ui-jqgrid {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        table {
            table-layout: fixed;
        }

        table th,
        table td {
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        .table-light tbody+tbody,
        .table-light td,
        .table-light th,
        .table-light thead th {
            border-color: #b8c3c3;
        }

        th.ui-th-column div {
            white-space: normal !important;
            height: auto !important;
            padding: 2px;
        }

        .ui-jqdialog-content .FormGrid {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: inherit;
        }

        .ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-titlebar {
            height: 30px;
        }

        .fm-button {
            height: auto;
        }

        .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar {
            height: 25px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>jqGrid Edit Rows Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://js.kintone.com/jqgrid/v5.4.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.kintone.com/jqgrid/v5.4.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-ru.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://js.kintone.com/jqgrid/v5.4.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div id="grid_container" class="mt-5">
                    <table id="table-application">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div id="pager"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I use together jqGrid and select2. In edition mode, when navigation rows, values from row is not substituted in select. If I click button with arrow "next" or "previous" value of inputs, textarea are changed but value of select are not changed.

This happens if I use select2, without select2 it works right. How can I fix it go on using select2?
setting select2 is below

```
  {name: "status_name", id: "status_name", editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: {
     dataUrl:"/Operator/OperatorApplicationController/getSelect&table=status",
     dataInit: function (el) {
        $(el).select2({
        language: 'ru',
        width: '100%'
     });
   }}}
```

Comment: I used advice of Tony Tomov. It helped me to solve issue, everything works, but I am not sure that I change value of select a right way. Maybe there are more elegant options for working with select2.

Answer (score 0):

Since the select2 is external plugin used in jqGrid, maybe you will need to refresh its value when the prev/next button is click.
I have never try this, but you can use the afterclickPgButtons for the form edit button click event - [see docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#edit-grid-row) and undocumented change event in select2 - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17819709/359284#31856728)

This can look like this

```
$('#grid'). jqGrid('navGrid', pager, {params},
...
{ afterclickPgButtons : function(button, form, id ) { 
    $("#status_name").val(null).trigger('change.select2');
},...
} // edit options parameter
);
```

Mybe you will need to check if the id of the element is correct.

Comment: Thanks your advice. It helped me to solve issue, everything works, but I am not sure that I change value of select a right way. Maybe there are more elegant options for working with select2.
<code>                afterclickPgButtons: function (button, form, id) {
 let row = $('#' + id);
let cell = $(row).find(
 "td[aria-describedby='table-application_inventory_number']").text();
 $("#inventory_number").select2();
$("#inventory_number").val(cell);}</code>