# select2 does not autoselect when using optgroup

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using select2 with jqgrid.
something is not working correctly, these are the cases when I edit a row.

WITHOUT OPTGROUP

1. standard select (no select2) without optgroup: select will show the selected item (the one i’m editing)
2. select2 without optgroup: select will show the selected item (the one i’m editing)

WITH OPTGROUP

3. standard select (no select2) with optgroup: select will show the selected item (the one i’m editing)
4. select2 with optgroup: select will NOT show the selected item (the one i’m editing) but when I open it il will focus the selected item.

So as you see #2 works, my problem is #4. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Thank you,
Lorenzo

Comment: First - it is a good idea to know which version of jqGrid is used?  - and  second, without any code that demonstrates the problem it is very difficult to get help.

Comment: Hello tony. Sorry. I am using lastest jqgrid and lastest select2. I created a jsfiddle and the problem does not happen I think because I am not creating my select2 with ajax and mysql. How can i simulate it on jsfiddle? Anyway if you check it there's another problem I just found. Using standard select i can edit and change row and select will automatically update. Using select2 it will not update when changing row. You can uncomment lines 111-120 in here: https://jsfiddle.net/lorife/dusqww2w/

Comment: If you know how to simulate ajax and mysql on jsfiddle I can update the demo

Comment: In this site (stackoverflow) serach for **jqgrid select2** and you will find a very useful posts and solutions

Comment: I use this site every day but I did not find any solution about my problem, that is why I wrote here. I know how to use jqgrid with select2, I am having a specific problem when using select2 with optgroup and I edit a jqgrid row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you search, but the problem when navigating row is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57766776/jqgrid-with-select2-in-edition-mode-when-navigation-rows-values-from-row-is-n/57784196#57784196)

In your case I have tested and the following code work:

```
$('#grid'). jqGrid('navGrid', pager, {params},
...
  {  // edit params
     { afterclickPgButtons : function(button, form, id ) { 
        $("#name").trigger('change.select2');
     },...
  }
);
```

Note the difference of the link above.

**UPDATED**

In order to solve the problem you will need to use setTimeout within dataInit function. Try with one of the following settings:

```
{
      name: "name",
      index: "name",
      autosize: true,
      searchoptions:{clearSearch:false},
      width:200,
      editable:true,          
      edittype: 'select', 
      editoptions: {         
        // Simulo la risposta di una chiamata
        // Per funzionare deve esistere più sotto 
        // ajaxSelectOptions
        dataUrl:'/echo/html/',
        postData: {
                      html: serverResponce
                  }, 
        //            
        dataInit: function(element) { 
        setTimeout(function(){
              $(element).select2({
                allowClear: false,
                // Imposto il tema bootstrap
                theme: "bootstrap4",
                dropdownAutoWidth : true,
                        width: 'auto',                  
                placeholder: 'Search...'
              });
          }, 500);
            }
      }
   }
```

I expect to have a demo with optgroup

Comment: ok, thanks for that. I will try to produce a demo but first I have to understand how to simulate a mysql call using jsfiddle as it seems the problem is present just there. I will update you

Comment: Hello, finally i made it. here is the demo updated: https://jsfiddle.net/lorife/dusqww2w/

Comment: Hello Tony. Ok with timeout it works. It's not very nice to see because there's a flickering when it changes the select with the select2 but it works. Any way to solve that? thank you!

Comment: I have do not test it, but you can try with custom element. More [see here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#edittype) - see edittype : 'custom'