# onchange function calling infinity times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

Here i am creating table rows with two dropdowns

```
`
counter = 0;// Global Variable
function addNewRow(){
                counter++;
                $('#purchase_order').append('<tr id='+counter+'>' +
                    '<td>' +
                        '<select name="code'+counter+'" onchange="return getItemNamesByTypeID('+counter+')" class="form-control" id="code'+counter+'">' +
                            '<option value="0">--Item Code --</option>' +
                            '<?php
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM product_packing_relation WHERE sub_cat_id !=0000";
                                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                    {
                                        echo '<option value="'. $row["id"] .'">' . "PT_".$row['product_type_id']."_".$row['id'] .'</option>';
                                    }
                                ?>' +
                        '</select>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<select name="product'+counter+'" onchange="return getItemNamesByTypeID('+counter+')" class="form-control" id=product'+ counter +'>' +
                    '<option value="0">--Item Code --</option>' +
                    '<?php
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM vw_product_packing_relation";
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                            echo '<option value="'. $row["id"] .'">' . $row['product_name'].'_'.$row['item_size'].$row['item_unit'].'_'.$row['bundle_type'].'_'.$row['pack_size'] .'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>' +
                    '</select>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td><input class="form-control" type="test" name=uom'+ counter +' id=uom'+ counter +' /></td>' +
                    '</tr>');
                $("#code"+counter).select2();
                $("#product"+counter).select2();
            }`
```

Now i try to do that if user change any dropdown the selected key change the other dropdown here is the code.

```
`function getItemNamesByTypeID(counter){
                event.preventDefault();
                var product_packing_id=0;
                product_packing_id = $("#code" + counter + " option:selected").val();

                if(product_packing_id == 0)
                {
                    product_packing_id = $("#product" + counter + " option:selected").val();
                }
                alert(product_packing_id);
                debugger;
                $("#code"+counter).val(product_packing_id);
                $("#code"+counter).change();
                $("#product" + counter).val(product_packing_id);
                $("#product" + counter).change();
                return false;
            }`
```

Now the problem is if i change any dropdown it starts calling onchange function infinite times.

Comment: (offtopic: [MDN - Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) - thank me later ;) ) Make your code more readabe, place your PHP outside of JS. Pass only a single variable result  into JS.

Comment: You're triggering a change event within the change event handler...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have to change the other dropdown selected value that's why i call change method

Comment: The problem is caused by the fact that you trigger a change event on the element which listens for the change event. This causes the infinite loop. You need to restructure your JS to avoid that.

Comment: PS: try to never use `return false;` from a jQuery event callback - it's the same as doing preventDefault *and* the dangerous stopPropagation. You should never prevent an application from registering propagating events. There's not a single viable reason to do so that I'm aware of.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if i only use $("#code"+counter).val(product_packing_id); this statement then this have no effect on Dropdown, how can i change dropdown value without change event....? any suggestions.

Comment: Given the code you've provided, you do *not* need to call `$("#code"+counter).change();` in getItemNamesByTypeID as getItemNamesByTypeID has already done the updates to *both* drop downs that it needs to.   Remove both `.change()` calls ... **unless** you're using a wrapper like `select2` ... which you are (tag added)

Comment: @freedomn-m i try after removing both .change() calls, Dropdown only focus of that value when you open it but never shown as selected value

Comment: Yes, because you're using `select2` which needs to be "refreshed" - remove your select2 (while debugging/working on it) and you should see it working fine.

Comment: Yes you are right its working after removing select2 jquery, but i need to implement select2 library here, Is it possible that I use select2 library and perform this task.....?

Comment: You can refresh using the select2 namespace'd event:  `$("#code"+counter).trigger('change.select2');`  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31856728/2181514

Comment: @freedomn-m I use $("#code"+counter).select2('destroy'); to distroy and then give value to dropdown after assigning again put select2 and It Works Fine Thanks. Here is the Code...
$("#code"+counter).select2('destroy');
$("#code"+counter).val(product_packing_id).select2();
$("#product" + counter).select2('destroy');
$("#product" + counter).val(product_packing_id).select2();